# mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/var/log/spark-jobserver\r’: Permission denied

Tags: linux, apache-spark, permissions, amazon-emr, spark-jobserver

I was trying to deploy spark-jobserver on a EMR cluster, as per this documentation "https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/doc/EMR.md#configure-master-box"

Was able to install the job-server on emr, but while starting the server using ./server_start.sh on "/mnt/lib/spark-jobserver" (you can find it in my cluster), it was showing
"mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/var/log/spark-jobserver\r’: Permission denied".

I have tried to give permission to it using chmod and also tried chown command, but all of these didnt work.

Further I had also tried logging in with ec2-user, but this even didnt help.

Can you please tell what more else is needed to be done in order to get it deployed on emr, or emr is not capable of doing this.

Logs:
[hadoop@ip-10-0-0-50 spark-jobserver]$ `./server_start.sh`
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/var/log/spark-jobserver\r’: Permission denied

Comment: Have you tried running it with `sudo`?

Comment: Yes. Still didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Did you try giving permissions recursively?

```
chmod -R 777 dirname
```